# Se puede mostrar html de jQuery sin referencia?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Cómo puedo generar un html con jQuery sin que use un elemento como referencia?, a lo que me refiero es que normalmente para pintar un html generado en jQuery se debe referenciar a dónde se va a pintar por ejemplo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p></p> //No quiero que se referencie a ese párrafo, si no solo se genere desde 0 en el jQuery


</body>
</html>
```

Respondiendo al comentario lo que quiero hacer es imprimir en cada for de un PHP una variable pero al iterar solo me imprime la última que se ejecuta por ejemplo si tengo una lista del 1 al 5 (itera correctamente en la consola) solo imprime el 5 en todos, yo digo que es porque se usa el mismo div(el mismo nombre por así decirlo) para imprimir, a continuación pongo el código para mayor explicación.

```
<!-- php foreach-->
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {                            
                            var id= num_id;
                            console.log(id);
                            $('.id').text("id: "+id);
                        });

</script>

<div class="id"></div>
<!-- php endforeach -->
```

Comment: Debes entender que html es un lenguaje estructurado, por lo tanto necesita una estructura (elemento) donde poner el contenido. En este caso lo que seguramente quieres decir es que lo ponga en el elemento <body>, con lo cual puedes usar `$("body").html("Hello <b>world!</b>")` para ello

Comment: Entonces como le puedo hacer para que se imprima el valor de una función que está dentro de un for de php si tengo que referenciarlo a fuerzas a un párrafo

Comment: Porque solo me muestra el último ya que ese párrafo tiene el mismo id o clase

Comment: debes poner el codigo de esa funcion para que la veamos, seguramente estas haciendo todo el rato un `.html()` en lugar de un `.append()` con lo cual estas sobreescribiendolo en cada ciclo del bucle, y finalmente se muestra solo el último por eso. Edita tu pregunta pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para agregar el código de esa función para que podamos ver lo que haces y confirmar tus errores.

Comment: @masterguru ya edite la pregunta con lo que decías

Comment: Bien hecho, ahora se entiende mejor todo. Lo que yo haria en este caso es agregar una clase más al `<div>`, por ejemplo, `numdiv`, y concatenarle un número correspondiente al ciclo por el que está pasando, de tal forma que en la primera pasada se llamaria `numdiv1`, en la segunda `numdiv2`, etc... y donde haces el `text` quitar el `.id` y usar `.numdiv{x}` donde x representa el número de ciclo y las llaves el sistema que estes usando para introducir variables de php en esa plantilla. El div quedaria así tambien: `<div class="id numdiv{x}"></div>`.

Comment: De este modo no pierdes la forma de llamarlos a todos a la vez (con la clase `id`) y consigues asignar a cada uno el valor de cada ciclo (con la clase `numdiv{x}` y el `$('.numdiv{x}').text("id: "+id);`)... Eso seria la solución tosca pero funcionaria. Aún así, queda bastante feo y raro lo que haces, pues para rellenar el div te basas en javascript cuando seguramente no te haria falta en este caso y podrias hacerlo todo en php directamente, aunque tambien estoy hablando a ciegas pues no veo de donde sale el `num_id` ni porque cambia en javascript.

Comment: @masterguru listo ya quedó con lo que me comentaste gracias, si era ponerle un número al div para cuando pasara no se repitiera

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya funcionado. Si acaso cuelga tu mismo la respuesta a tu pregunta con la solución que finalmente has aplicado y en 48 horas podras aceptartela tu mismo, así la pregunta no quedara pendiente de respuesta eternamente, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

si se puede, asi, se hace:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
    
    $('body').append(' //No quiero que se referencie a ese párrafo, si no solo se genere desde 0 en el jQuery');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p></p>


</body>
</html>
```